# Raspberry Pi 3 B+ Portable Power Supply

Tags: raspbian

I wanted to buy a Portable Power Supply for Raspberry Pi 3 b.. I found this on Amazon... Will this power supply support raspberry Pi 3 b. [image]

Comment: Keep in mind that many USB battery banks do *not* provide power while they are themselves charging. To keep your Pi running you must get a power supply that provides "passthrough" (or some equivalent term), and this feature is not widely or accurately noted.

Comment: What do people mean by "opinon-based" here? RPi power specs are not really an opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, it'll work well.

According to documentation on the [official Raspberry Pi website](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/power/README.md)

> We have found that purchasing a 2.5A power supply from a reputable retailer will provide you with ample power to run your Raspberry Pi.

The product you posted has 5V 2.4A, meaning its incredibly close to the [official power supply](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-universal-power-supply/) of 5V 2.5A